# Is it possible to style a CSS class relative to another CSS class (not outer class)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So, here's a snippet of my HTML:

```
<div class="stepwizard__step"> 
  <a class="btn btn-primary stepwizard__btn">1</a>
  <p class="stepwizard__step-text">Payment</p>
</div>
```

Basically, what I want to do is, every time there's a Bootstrap primary button (`.btn-primary`), I want to change the color of the `.stepwizard__step-text` (in this case, "Payment") to red.

Is this possible?

My first instinct was to try something like this:

```
.btn-primary > .stepwizard__step-text {
  color: red;
}
```

but then I realized that won't work because the `stepwizard__step-text` class isn't inside the `btn-primary` class.

I realize this is a bit of stretch, but is there a way in CSS to check if the `btn-primary` class exists inside of `stepwizard__step` and if it does, to change the color of `stepwizard__step-text` to red? If not, can anyone think of another way to do this?

Comment: Will the `p` to be styled *always* immediately follow the `a.btn-primary`.

Comment: in this case, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.
>
> **Note:** Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.

So, you must use `+` Selector :

> The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.

**Read More :**

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

**In your Case Change Code Like:**

```css
.btn-primary + p.stepwizard__step-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepwizard__step">
    <a class="btn btn-primary stepwizard_btn">1</a>
    <p class="stepwizard__step-text">Payment</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way in CSS to check if the `btn-primary` class exists inside of `stepwizard__step` and if it does, to change the color of `stepwizard__step-text` to red?

Yes, but only if `stepwizard__step-text` comes *after* the `btn-primary`. This is because rules only go down the DOM tree, never to parent elements or predecessors.

The rules can be built as follows:

1. Select a `.btn-primary` inside `.stepwizard__step`...

   ```
   .stepwizard__step .btn-primary
   ```
2. ...and target a `.stepwizard__step-text` coming [right after it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

   ```
   .stepwizard__step .btn-primary + .stepwizard__step-text
   ```

If there can be elements between the `.btn-primary` and `.stepwizard__step-text`, use a [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) instead of a `+` in the last selector. This is the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Your example would then become something like the following.

```css
.stepwizard__step .btn-primary ~ .stepwizard__step-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepwizard__step">
  <a class="btn btn-primary stepwizard_btn">1</a>
  <p class="stepwizard__step-text">Payment</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "This is because rules only go down the DOM tree (CSS = cascading style sheets)." Common misconception; the cascade in CSS has nothing to do with tree traversal. But other than that, this is the only answer worth upvoting.

Comment: @BoltClock Really? Well, today I learned. I̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶  I removed it from my answer and will do some reading then :-)

Comment: In a nutshell, the cascade refers to per-element style resolution. Stuff like specificity, multiple declarations, inline styles, !important, etc. Inheritance is one aspect of the cascade that *does* involve the transfer of property values from a parent to a child, but style resolution ultimately still happens locally. And as you can imagine, inheritance does not occur from a preceding sibling to a following sibling.

Comment: @BoltClock Right, the cascading part is broader, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```css
.btn-primary+p.stepwizard__step-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepwizard__step">
  <a class="btn btn-primary stepwizard_btn">1</a>
  <p class="stepwizard__step-text">Payment</p>
</div>
```

Hope it works for your use!

Comment: @ehsan umm, I didn't copy your answer? But yes, I do see that our answers are pretty similar.

Comment: that worked! thanks so much! I'm so relieved to know that this can be done!

Comment: @Sreetam Das: Probably to go with his accusation.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't see me writing my own answer *which happens to be similar* to another, being a reason for a downvote. [Context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):
 **When should I vote down?**
_Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect._

Comment: @Sreetam Das: Yeah, but sadly that doesn't stop ehsan from voting based on his bitterness towards you. People misuse their votes all the time I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

> .stepwizard__step > a + p{color:red;}

or

> .stepwizard__step a + p{color:red;}

or

> .stepwizard__step .btn-primary + p{color:red;}

or

> .stepwizard__step .btn-primary + .stepwizard__step-text{color:red;}

Let me know if there is any other confusion?

Comment: For what was asked, those are all wrong, bar the last one.